# Chain two ssh portforwards

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, ssh

I've been browsing through answers here on superuser, however no answers I found addresses my use case.

I want to chain two commands I use that let me tunnel through a tunnel:

```
ssh -L 22:hostB:22 user@hostA
```

and

```
ssh -L 10002:localhost:10001 user@localhost
```

Right now what I do is enter the first command, open another terminal, and enter the second one. If I do something like

```
ssh … && ssh …
```

the second command executes only after I "exit" from the first connection.

More advanced ssh options like jumphost do not work due to server configuration on hostA, so I'm pretty sure this is the only option to have 10001 port accessible like this.

Is there a way to chain those two commands into one alias, or use some simple bash script with timeouts, etc?

Comment: Could you provide more detail about why JumpHost does not work? It uses exactly the same SSHv2 "direct-tcpip" request as -L does...

Comment: Well I get permission denied on hostA if I try something with -J flag. My admin (it's a company network) told me to use it in such a way instead of JumpHost.

Comment: Does that happen during authentication, or afterwards? Could you provide ssh -v logs of that happening?

Comment: After authenticating to the jump host. https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/6SHsF2JfS4/

Comment: That's odd, because -J or JumpHost basically expands to `ssh hostA -W hostB:22` which is nearly indistinguishable from `ssh hostA -N -L 12345:hostB:22`...

Comment: You could add the options `-f` (go into the background) and `-N` (don't execute a remote command) to the first `ssh`, then the `&&` approach should work. But you could also try using one of the old [ProxyCommand methods](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH%2FCookbook%2FProxies_and_Jump_Hosts#Old_Methods_of_Passing_Through_Jump_Hosts) (with either `-W` or `nc`) instead of `-J`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you cannot do just `ssh -L 10002:hostB:10001 user@hostA` because

- either whatever listens on B's `10001` binds to the local interface only,
- or the firewall on B disallows connection to `hostB:10001` from A,
- or whatever.

---

> ```
> ssh … && ssh …
> ```
>
> the second command executes only after I "exit" from the first connection.

Yes, this is normal. The part before `&&` must terminate and return exit status before the next command is run (or not, depending on the status).

This will run the second `ssh` almost immediately but it's flawed:

```
( ssh … & ) && ssh …
```

It's flawed because the first `ssh` has no impact on the second one. The second one will probably run way before the first one establishes the tunnel. Asking for passwords may also get problematic.

For this usage case `ssh` has `-f` option. From [`man 1 ssh`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh):

> `-f`
>   Requests `ssh` to go to background just before command execution. […]

So the basic command may be:

```
ssh -fNL 22:hostB:22 user@hostA && ssh -NL 10002:localhost:10001 user@localhost
```

It's up to you whether you want to use `-N` with the second `ssh` or not. Now the trick is the first `ssh` forks to the background after asking for password (if applicable) and after establishing the first tunnel, so temporarily there are two "first" `ssh` processes. The one in the background starts handling the tunnel; the one in the foreground exits, this allows `&&` to work.

You probably want `-o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes`. If the first tunnel cannot be established, the first `ssh` will exit unsuccessfully and the second one won't run. The improved command is:

```
ssh -fNL 22:hostB:22 \
    -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes \
    user@hostA &&
ssh -NL 10002:localhost:10001 user@localhost
```

Note when the second `ssh` exits, the first one (in the background) remains. The advantage is you can run the sole second `ssh` later. The disadvantage is you'll need to kill the first one manually if you don't want it to remain. With this in mind consider the following approach:

```
ssh -fNL 22:hostB:22 \
    -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes \
    user@hostA
ssh -NL 10002:localhost:10001 user@localhost
```

Note there is no `&&`. Now if there is the old first `ssh` still running then the new one will fail because it won't be able to bind to the port. The second `ssh` will run regardless, it will use the first tunnel and it doesn't matter how old the tunnel is.

It may happen there is no old `ssh` and the first `ssh` fails for whatever reasons. If so, the second one will run and it will probably fail (connection refused) because there's nothing listening on the port `22`.

Still you may not want to leave an "idle" `ssh` process, you may want to terminate it automatically after the second `ssh` exits. Obviously `killall ssh` may cause collateral damage. Let's find something more subtle:

> `-M`
>   Places the `ssh` client into “master” mode for connection sharing. […]
>
> […]
>
> `-O ctl_cmd`
>   Control an active connection multiplexing master process. […]
>
> […]
>
> `-S ctl_path`
>   Specifies the location of a control socket for connection sharing […]

```
#!/bin/sh

socket=/tmp/hostA.socket

ssh -fNL 22:hostB:22 \
    -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes \
    -MS "$socket"
    user@hostA &&
{
ssh -NL 10002:localhost:10001 user@localhost
ssh -S "$socket" -O exit dummy
}
```

After the second `ssh` terminates, the third one will tell the first one to exit. In the third `ssh` command it's the socket that matters, not the hostname; still you need to provide some hostname, hence `dummy`. The first `ssh` will remove the socket before exiting, there should be no garbage left.

There are still few concerns:

- If the script is interrupted, the first `ssh` will remain. Either drop `&&` or send `-O exit` at the very beginning just in case (it would be the zeroth `ssh`).
- If the first `ssh` dies abruptly, the socket may remain. It will make any new first `ssh` fail. A good idea may be to expand the zeroth `ssh` like this:

  ```
  ssh -S "$socket" -O exit dummy || rm "$socket"
  ```
- `/tmp/hostA.socket` may not be the best location for the socket. In `ssh_config` the equivalent of `-S` command line option is `ControlPath`. See what [`man 5 ssh_config`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config.5) says about it:

  > It is recommended that any `ControlPath` used for opportunistic connection sharing include at least `%h`, `%p`, and `%r` (or alternatively `%C`) and be placed in a directory that is not writable by other users.

  A "directory that is not writable by other users" may be `/run/user/$UID`, if your OS supports it (I believe it's `systemd`'s thing).

Comment: What an amazing and informative answer, thank you very much. It works flawlessly.